# Is there a simple way to match a value in a csv file using python?

Tags: python, csv

Is there a simple way to match a value in a given field of a csv file using python without using a regex? I have a field in a csv file that contains text. I wish to write a python script to do stuff to all the fields that contain the text 'eagle' in a file called file.csv.

For example:

```
import csv

with open('file.csv', mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
        for row in reader:
            match = row[3]
            if match == 'eagle':
                DO STUFF
```

The above code does not work. How can I DO STUFF with all the row[3] values that match the string 'eagle'? Thanks for the help!

EDIT:
here are some examples lines from 'file.csv'

```
tree,rock,10000,eagle
plant,stone,500,owl
seed,boulder,7000,crane
fruit,pebble,60000000,hawk
```

I wish to match row[3] from line 1 and 4, then DO STUFF.

Comment: What exactly isn't working about the code you pasted?

Comment: My code does not throw an error. This section of my code simply does not execute. row[3] is at the end of of the row if that helps.

Comment: Also, the string 'eagle' that I wish to match  is the only text in row[3].

Comment: Could you add some example lines from your csv file?

Comment: Also, what do you get if you `print 'a' + row[3] + 'a'`? The `a`s are so you will see empty space at the beginning and end of the item.

Answer (score 1):

It works on my machine.

```
bash-4.1$ cat > file.csv
tree,rock,10000,eagle
plant,stone,500,owl
seed,boulder,7000,crane
fruit,pebble,60000000,hawk
bash-4.1$ python
Python 2.7 (r27:82500, Sep 16 2010, 18:03:06) 
[GCC 4.5.1 20100907 (Red Hat 4.5.1-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import csv
>>> 
>>> with open('file.csv', mode='r') as infile:
...     reader = csv.reader(infile)
...     for row in reader:
...         match = row[3]
...         if match == 'eagle':
...             print(repr(match))
... 
'eagle'
```

Comment: It also works for me. Try printing `repr(row[3])` to see what it actually is.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting your line by ',' will works if no data contains the ',' character.

```
string.split(row,",")
```

http://docs.python.org/library/string.html